# Computer-aided remover of already-sorted images

Tags: image, duplicates, photos

My question is **not** removing duplicated/similar images. I need a tool to process a more complex process:

1. **Find pictures I have manually removed in a folder**
2. **Apply this removal in another folder**
3. **Replace low-resolution pictures in a folder by High-resolution ones from another folder**

I use Linux, but please propose solutions compatible with several OS if possible. I would also appreciate [Free/Libre/OpenSource](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free/Libre_Open_Source_Software) tools.

---

#### The below three examples explain the requirements

-1- **Basic example:** I have an old copy of my *SD card* on my computer (where I have already removed *failed* pictures) and I want these *failed* pictures (*worst* ones) be automatically removed from my Camera's *SD card*.

```
Folder "My-Computer"    Folder "SD-Card"      ACTION
I23001.JPG              I23001.JPG            keep duplicate
I23002.JPG              I23002.JPG            keep duplicate
                        I23003.JPG            remove missing
                        I23004.JPG            remove missing
I23005.JPG              I23005.JPG            keep duplicate
                        I23006.JPG            remove missing
                        I23007.JPG            remove missing
I23008.JPG              I23008.JPG            keep duplicate
                        I23009.JPG            copy new picture
                        I23010.JPG            copy new picture
                        I23011.JPG            copy new picture
```

In real life, pictures are also copied on mobile phones, web gallery, cloud, backup... and *failed* pictures may also be removed on different devices...

-2- **More complex example:** I take picture using camera/smartphone/tablet. I also manually remove *failed* pictures (*worst* ones) on computer/camera/smartphone/tablet. We want best pictures being copied an all devices to view/show them.

```
"My-Computer"  "SD-Card"    "Smartphone"   ACTION
I23001.JPG     I23001.JPG   I23001.JPG     keep duplicate
I23002.JPG     I23002.JPG                  ask user
               I23003.JPG   I23003.JPG     ask user
               I23004.JPG                  remove missing
I23005.JPG     I23005.JPG   I23005.JPG     keep duplicate
P89001.JPG                  P89001.JPG     keep duplicate
P89002.JPG                  P89002.JPG     keep duplicate
P89003.JPG                                 remove missing
P89004.JPG                  P89004.JPG     keep duplicate
I23006.JPG     I23006.JPG                  remove missing
I23007.JPG     I23007.JPG                  remove missing
I23008.JPG     I23008.JPG   I23008.JPG     keep duplicate
               I23009.JPG                  copy new picture
               I23010.JPG                  copy new picture
               I23011.JPG                  copy new picture
P89005.JPG                  P89005.JPG     keep duplicate
                            P89006.JPG     copy new picture
                            P89007.JPG     copy new picture
                            P89008.JPG     copy new picture
```

-3- **Very complex:** I copy pictures from my camera to my smartphone using the camera's Wi-Fi access point, **but the pictures are reduced (similar image content but not exact duplicate file)**. I also copy pictures to my friend's smartphone. We also take photos using our smartphone and copy some ones (*best* ones) to the other smartphone. And we also process the same with tablets. Manual removal is done on any device.

```
example too messed to be displayed here!
```

---

#### Analysis

List of duplicates finders:

- [Duplicate file finders on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_duplicate_file_finders)
- Search word *"duplicate"* in [image viewer comparison on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_image_viewers)

Interesting tools:

- [`findimagedups` from Jonathan H N Chin](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/), perl script (and C lib) storing image fingerprints into a Berkley DB file and printing together filenames of images matching more than xx% similarity (pictures taken in burst mode may be flagged as similar)
- [`findimagedupes` version in Go](https://github.com/opennota/findimagedupes)
- [gThumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GThumb) can also [find/remove duplicates](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/gthumb-2131-released-with-find.html)
- [Geeqie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geeqie)
- [imgSeek](http://www.imgseek.net/)
- [digiKam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiKam) and its [Find Duplicate Images Tool](http://www.digikam.org/node/333)
- Visipics
- [dupeGuru Picture Edition](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/)

Tools lacking of similar image recognition:

- [fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/)
- `duff`
- [`fdups`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes)
- [`rmlint`](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint)

---

#### Coding a new tool

As I did not (yet) find any solution I was thinking of developing a new software:

- Modify a command line tools like `findimagedups` in order to provide the matching distance between images (similarity percentage)
- This output may be a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29)

  - each file is a *node*
  - *edges* (relations between files):

    - content matching (similarity percentage, crop, similar region)
    - in same folder, in a neighborhood folder
    - similar filename, successive filename numbering
    - similar date/time
    - similar metadata
    - similar resolution
- For each group of content-similar nodes

  - one folder = one column
  - one file by raw, if duplicates in same folder (e.g. burst mode)
  - missing file in one folder = blank
  - similarity of files are provided in horizontal/vertical neighborhood only
- Automatically selection of:

  - files to be replaced (low resolution replaced by high resolution, except in folder called *"small"*)
  - files to be removed
- User can display pictures and check connection properties